# Why C# compares "the same" floating numbers in C# different

Tags: c#, floating-point, floating-accuracy

```
float a = 0.95f;
float b = 5.05f;
float ab = (a + b);
bool isTrue = (ab == 6.0f);
bool isFalse = ((a + b) == 6.0f);
bool isTrueAgain = ((float)(a + b) == 6.0f);
```

Why *isTrue* is true?

Why *isFalse* is false?

[image]

Comment: Funny addition: `ab == (a + b)` equals `false`

Comment: These may be of interest - http://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2014/12/22/redundant-cast.html https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf (12.1.3)

Comment: In summary - `(a + b)` doesn't have to be a `float` on the last line (according to the C# spec) - so its value can be different to that shown on the third line. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/spRgWV .